# how to exclude another attribute in this syntext [Bind(Exclude = "ID")] in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

as I've excluded "ID", how can i exclude another attribute?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Exclude takes a comma-separated list of attributes.  When parsed it also trims the inputs so you can use whitespace to make it more readable.

Example:

```
[Bind(Exclude="ID, Name")]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Bind(Exclude="ID,Second")]

Answer (score 2):

Try delimiting the attributes you want to exclude with commas, e.g.

```
[Bind(Exclude="ID,Name")]
```